# How to redirect only post to subfolder in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

First thanks for supports.

I'm using WordPress for my site. My posts with URL like example:

```
http://domain.com/this-is-my-post-url
```

So, how to redirect all posts in my site to subfolder (only post). New URL of my posts is:

```
http://domain.com/article/this-is-my-post-url
```

My temporarily way is redirect per URL:

```
RedirectPermanent /this-is-my-post-url /article/this-is-my-post-url
```

But my site have much posts. This way is not good.

Any idea for me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this via .htaccess

A way you could achieve this is the following:
In wordpress create a category named `article` and make it your default (this can be done in `settings->writing->default post category`)

This would then in your slug, result in `article/postname`

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But this solution is not support for error 404 when user viewed the post if I have change the post's URL.

Answer (score -1):

This is very easy to accomplish.  From the Dashboard, go to Settings --> Permalinks.  Under "Common Structure", choose "Custom" and insert "/article" before "/%postname%/".  The resulting input will be

```
/article/%postname%/
```

Finally, click "Save Changes".

Comment: Thanks for reply. May be you're not understand the question. Of course I must do your step, but old URLs in Google, Bing... still leads users to old posts URL. Then, users go to the 404 error page. That is my problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.  I'm afraid I agree with Krystof that there is no way to accomplish this unless all your posts' names have a certain characteristic that other pages' names do not have.